# Hide Document Library from non-owner users

Tags: document-library, permissions, office-365

How to maintain a Document Library for owners and hide that library from other site members ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break permission inheritance of that document library. Remove other users. Then only assign permission to the owners. This will hide the library from other users.

Comment: i have tried , but still its its visible to  site members .

Comment: It should work. Can you see if the site members has been given permissions via other groups. Also confirm you removed all users/groups from the library advanced permission settings page.